# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to search for a certain number within a Text Document. It reads the file fine, and using the same code later can print fine, but when I tell it to find a  certain number in the Text Document it tells me `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not _io.TextIOWrapper`. I have looked all around but all questions say 'not str' whereas mine says 'not _io.TextIOWrapper'

This is my code (I am going down route 'A' under 'menuOptions'

```
import time
import linecache
print("Welcome to the League Fixture Manager!")
time.sleep(3)
print("What would you like to do?")
time.sleep(1)
print("Press A to search for a fixture.")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("Press B to view Outstanding fixtures.")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("Press C to display the leader board")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("Or press Q to quit, this will exit the application.")
time.sleep(0.1)
menuOptions = input("What would you like to do? A, B, C, or Q.")
if menuOptions == 'A':
    print("Please enter the fixture number you are looking for... ")
    fixtureQuestion = input(int())
    fixtureQuestion = int(fixtureQuestion)
    fixtureQuestion = fixtureQuestion - (1)
    time.sleep(3)
    if fixtureQuestion < 1:
        print("This fixture is not available, please re-run the application...")
        time.sleep(2)
        exit()
    elif fixtureQuestion > 190:
        print("This fixture is not available, please re-run the application...")
        time.sleep(2)
        exit()
    else:
        searchData = open("Y:\Computing & Business\Students\Computing\Year 10\CA 2017 Edexcel\\firesideFixtures.txt")
        lines = searchData.readlines()
        print(lines[searchData])
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Return to menu?")
        menuReturn = input("Y or N")
        if menuReturn == 'Y':
            print("Press B to view outstanding fixtures.")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("Press C to display the leaderboard")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("Or press Q to exit the application.")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("You cannot review the fixture list now you have seen it however you can scroll up to view it again.")
            time.sleep(0.1)
            menuOptions2 = input("What would you like to do? B, C, or Q?")
            if menuOptions2 == 'B':
                print("~~incomplete~~")
            elif menuOptions2 == 'C':
                print("~~incomplete~~")
            elif menuOptions2 == 'Q':
                print("Exiting Application...")
                time.sleep(1)
                exit()
        elif menuReturn == 'N':
            print("Exiting Application...")
            time.sleep(2)
            exit()
elif menuOptions == 'B':
    print("Searching for fixtures...")
    time.sleep(3)
    data = [line.strip() for line in open(r"Y:\Computing & Business\Students\Computing\Year 10\CA 2017 Edexcel\firesideFixtures.txt").readlines()]
    for line in data:
        print(line)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Return to menu?")
    menuReturn = input("Y or N")
    if menuReturn == 'Y':
        print("Press A to search for a fixture")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Press C to display the leaderboard")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Or press Q to exit the application.")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("You cannot review the fixture list now you have seen it however you can scroll up to view it again.")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        menuOptions2 = input("What would you like to do? B, C, or Q?")
        if menuOptions2 == 'A':
            fixtureQuestion = input(int("Please enter the fixture number you are looking for... "))
            fixtureQuestion = fixtureQuestion - 1
            time.sleep(3)
            if fixtureQuestion < 1:
                print("This fixture is not available, please re-run the application...")
                time.sleep(2)
                exit()
            elif fixtureQuestion > 190:
                print("This fixture is not available, please re-run the application...")
                time.sleep(2)
                exit()
            else:
                searchData = open(r"Y:\Computing & Business\Students\Computing\Year 10\CA 2017 Edexcel\firesideFixtures.txt").readlines()
                lines = searchData.readlines()
                print(lines[fixtureQuestion])
                time.sleep(1)
                print("Return to menu?")
                menuReturn = input("Y or N")
                if menuReturn == 'Y':
                    print("Press C to display the leaderboard")
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    print("Or press Q to exit the application.")
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    print("You cannot review the fixture list now you have seen it however you can scroll up to view it again.")
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    menuOptions2 = input("What would you like to do? B, C, or Q?")
                    if menuOptions2 == 'C':
                        print("~~incomplete~~")
                    elif menuOptions2 == 'Q':
                        print("Exiting Application...")
                        time.sleep(1)
                        exit()
                elif menuReturn == 'N':
                    print("Exiting Application...")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    exit()
                elif menuOptions2 == 'Q':
                    print("Exiting Application...")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    exit()
elif menuOptions == 'C':
    while RetryForC == "Yes":
        RetryForC == "No"
        fireRead = open("Y:\Computing & Business\Students\Computing\Year 10\CA 2017 Edexcel\firesideResults.txt")
        for line in fireRead:
            fireRead = open("Y:\Computing & Business\Students\Computing\Year 10\CA 2017 Edexcel\firesideResults.txt")
            InfoOne = line.split(',')[0]
            InfoTwo = line.split(',')[1]
            InfoThree = line.split(',')[2]
            InfoFour = line.split(',')[3]
            PointCounter = int(line.split(',')[2])
            PointCounter = PointCounter * 3
            fireRead.close()
            print("Player:",InfoOne,"Has played:",InfoTwo,", has won:",InfoThree,", has lost:",InfoFour,", and therefore has",PointCounter,"many points.")
        print("Retry?")
        RestForC = str(input("Yes/No  "))
    print("The program will now close...")
    time.sleep(5)
    exit()
elif menuOptions == 'Q':
    print("Exiting Applicaion...")
    time.sleep(2)
    exit()
```

And this is my result:

```
Welcome to the League Fixture Manager!
What would you like to do?
Press A to search for a fixture.
Press B to view Outstanding fixtures.
Press C to display the leader board
Or press Q to quit, this will exit the application.
What would you like to do? A, B, C, or Q.A
Please enter the fixture number you are looking for... 
016
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python Work\League\League3.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(lines[searchData])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

This line:

```
print(lines[searchData])
```

Doesn't make any sense. Indices of a list must be integers, so you can do:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list[0]
1
```

`lines` is a list which contains the lines of the file and `search_data` is a file object. It looks like you're missing some basic python concepts. Please do read the documentation I pasted in your other question you asked 10 minutes ago!

Comment: Thank you for the reply (and I am sorry that I seem really dumb...) I have just read the documentation you pasted about lines, however it doesn't say anything about reading it from a text file and printing it. I copied your code but it just says `my_List[0] NameError: name 'my_List' is not defined` I know that is saying that it wasn't defined but I'm not sure how to define it. It never says anything about that in the documentation